# Package Jython app as JAR in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jar, jython

We are currently considering using Netbeans to develop a Jython application and I am in the process of evaluating Netbeans' features.

It appears that creating a Jython application is trivial in Netbeans once the Python and Jython modules are installed. Yet I couldn't find a feature which would let we wrap my Jython app as a JAR file with all its dependencies. Is this possible with Netbeans or with some other IDE or do I need to do this kind of packaging by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried jump

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jump/0.9.7.4

[jump Homepage](http://web.archive.org/web/20100109113350/http://opensource.ollix.com/jump)

Features :

- Distributing Jython applications into a single, independent JAR file.
- Distributing Jython libraries into a single JAR file. [New in v0.9.5]
- Distributing native Mac OS X application bundles, Windows .exe executables, WAR files for Python WSGI applications. [New in v0.9.5]
- Distributing Java Only applications. [New in v0.9.6]
- Creating build.xml file for ant. [New in v0.9.7]
- Supporting Java source code and third-party JAR files.
- Supporting Java Native Interface files for distributing JAR files. [New in v0.9.5]
- Starting the created distribution from either Jython or Java code.
- Including specified resource files in the final distribution. [New in v0.9.6]
- Packaging only required Python packages into the final distribution automatically, which means you don't have to worry about using Python third-party libraries as long as they can be found in your sys.path.
- Importing specified Python packages explicitly. [New in v0.9.5]
- All Python modules included in the final distribution are compiled to $py.class files, which means your source code is not public.
- Integrated easy use Jython factory. [New in v0.9.7]

[Quick-start Guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20100109113501/http://opensource.ollix.com/jump/wiki/QuickStartGuide)

---

There is also a info in the [jython-wiki](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/) (not jump related)

In brief:

1. Jar file: run `jump jar --main-entry-point=file:main` (where `file` is the name of the Python script file and `main` is the application's `main` method/entry point
2. WAR file: run `jump war --main-entry-point=file:main --war-wsgi-handler=...`

The various options available for jump can be shown by outputting help/usage information: run `jump --help`.

Comment: The site/page linked to (quickstart Guide) seems to have disappeared. The Wayback machine has an entry [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100109113501/http://opensource.ollix.com/jump/wiki/QuickStartGuide), dated 09 Jan 2010. It doesn't show how to make library files or war files, although this can be worked out from passing `--help` to the jump binary.